# Webs scraping links from a business newspaper

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am a social scientist dabbling in web scraping. I have been trying to  scrape the links from this [Page](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archive/year-2021,month-1.cms)  The links for daily news is arranged within a table structure. This is my code

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverLocation,chrome_options=options)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()


url='https://economictimes.indiatimes.com//archive/year-2021,month-1.cms'

browser.get(url)

table = browser.find_element(By.ID,"calender");
rows=table.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
td=rows.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "td")      
print(td.get_attribute('href'))
```

The `get_attribute` returns nothing .I have tried a lot of other combinations -by Xpath etc but it's not working for me. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Cause td in your code is pointing here `#calender > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)` and there's no href.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you meant to scrape all the links under td a tag, You can try the below solution.

**Code :**

```
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
browser.get("https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archive/year-2021,month-1.cms")

hrefs = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#calender td a")))

for href in hrefs:
    print(href.get_attribute('href'))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44197.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44197.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44197.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44197.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44197.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44197.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44198.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44199.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44200.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44201.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44202.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44203.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44204.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44205.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44206.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44207.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44208.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44209.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44210.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44211.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44212.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44213.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44214.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44215.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44216.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44217.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44218.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44219.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44220.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44221.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44222.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44223.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44224.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44225.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44226.cms
https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/archivelist/year-2021,month-1,starttime-44227.cms
```